# Mysql select with ID's from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Ive got a couple of tables, exhibitions, languages, forms and questions. The questions have a `lang_id` and `form_id` in their table, and the exhibitions have got a `form_id` in the table. I want to select the languages which are linked to the forms. The only thing that is known is the exhibition id. How this is done?

You can get the form_id from the exhibitions table, with the known exhibition id. Then you can select the questions from that `form_id` and with that data you can check which languages are linked to the questions. But how do I accomplish this query?

Here is a sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bb726

The query I got is this one:

```
SELECT f.id, f.name  
FROM app_languages f,
     app_exhibition b,
     app_vragen_translations v 
WHERE f.id = b.form_id
  AND b.id = 4
  AND v.lang_id;
```

Comment: Where is the question table in the fiddle?

Comment: app_vragen  is the question table

Comment: app_vragen is not included in the sqlfiddle, only app_vragen_translation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't use your fiddle because you describe the problem so well that the query is so simple.

Your need to build name of your table and column better than that. With a good looking schema, the query you describe is this one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT lang.id, lang.name  
FROM exhibition
    INNER JOIN form
        ON exhibition.formId = form.id
        INNER JOIN question
            ON form.Id = question.formId
            INNER JOIN translation
                ON translation.formId = form.id
                INNER JOIN lang
                    ON translation.langId = lang.id
WHERE exhibition.id = 4
```

Here is the query with the fiddle :

```
SELECT DISTINCT app_languages.id, app_languages.name
FROM app_exhibition
    INNER JOIN app_forms
        ON app_exhibition.form_id = app_forms.id
        INNER JOIN app_vragen
            ON app_forms.id = app_vragen.form_id
            INNER JOIN app_vragen_translations
                ON app_vragen_translations.vraag_id = app_vragen.id
                INNER JOIN app_languages
                    ON app_vragen_translations.lang_id = app_languages.id
WHERE app_exhibition.id = 4
```

Results `app_exhibition.id = 4`

```
id  name
4   German
```

More results if using the other exhibition `app_exhibition.id = 5`

```
id  name
7   Dutch
2   English
```

Some hints :

- Use plain english and not your local langage. There is plenty reason for that, one of them is that it is easier to have answer on stackoverflow
- Don't use implicit joins (joins in the WHERE clause), but use JOIN clause instead. The query becomes more readable, and the difference between JOINING and FILTERING is obvious. JOIN is for joining, WHERE is for filtering. WHERE is NOT for joining.

Note : `exhibition` and `question` are referencing the field `formId`, so the join on the table `form` can be omitted if no further info are needed from this table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT app_languages.id, app_languages.name
FROM app_exhibition
    INNER JOIN app_vragen
        ON app_exhibition.form_id = app_vragen.form_id
        INNER JOIN app_vragen_translations
            ON app_vragen_translations.vraag_id = app_vragen.id
            INNER JOIN app_languages
                ON app_vragen_translations.lang_id = app_languages.id
WHERE app_exhibition.id = 4
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Yeah, I was in the process of renaming my code to use English instead of Dutch.

Comment: About the answer, the query is a bit messy because you used the wrong table names. But I think your answer works as well...

Comment: I forgot one table, it should be better now!

Comment: I marked your answer as right because you was right after all.